# Install .Net Framework 4.6.1 using Ansible

Tags: .net, ansible, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to install .Net Framework 4.6.1 using Ansible but until now I have no luck.

I've tried those methods:

1. Running a win_package to install it, but it just hangs till infinity

   ```
   - name: Install Microsoft NET Framework
     win_package:
       path: "http://path/to/dotNetFramework4.6.1.exe"
       product_id: '{BD6F5371-DAC1-30F0-9DDE-CAC6791E28C3}'
       register: dotnetfx_exe
   ```
2. Run a PowerShell script to install it (first doesn't work and second throws stack-overflow exception):

   ```
   Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core -source C:\temp\dotNetFramework4.6.1.exe
   ```

   Or

   ```
   Start-Process -FilePath C:\temp\dotNetFramework4.6.1.exe -ArgumentList "/q /norestart" -Wait -Verb RunAs
   ```
3. I've tried to use win_feature to install it, but it just do nothing.

   ```
   - name: Install NET-Framework-Core
     win_feature:
       name: NET-Framework-Core
       state: present
       source: C:\temp\dotNetFramework4.6.1.exe
       include_sub_features: no
       include_management_tools: yes
     register: result
   ```
4. Tried to run a batch script to install it, but no luck:

   ```
   start /wait c:\temp\dotNetFramework4.6.1.exe /q /norestart /log %TEMP%\dotNetFx4.6.1.log
   ```

Has anyone succeeded installing .Net Framework 4.6.1 using Ansible?

Could anyone share their task/role that installs it?

Answer (score 6):

We were calling Chocolatey via Ansible to install .NET 4.6.1, but ran into some complications with that. Instead I rewrote our playbook to do a "native" install. I imagine you ran into the same issues I did with trying to run the offline installer. This led me to your post and [this thread](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/installing-an-exe-with-powershell-dsc-package-resource-gets-return-code-16389/). Here is what I had to do to get it working.

Extract the contents of the offline installer:

```
NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /s /x /b"C:\tmp\dotnet\dotnet461" /v"/qn"
```

This command can uninstall .NET if it is already installed. I just ran it on a fresh vagrant VM instead of trying to get around that.

Zip up the contents of that folder, upload it to an internal host or network share, and then download/unzip/run it with your playbook.

```
  - name: Download Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 installer
    win_get_url:
      url: http://www.path.to/package/dotnet461.zip
      dest: C:\tmp\dotnet\dotnet461.zip

  - name: Unzip Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 installer
    win_unzip:
      src: C:\tmp\dotnet\dotnet461.zip
      dest: C:\tmp\dotnet
      rm: true

  - name: Run Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 installer
    raw: C:\tmp\dotnet\dotnet461\Setup.exe /q /norestart /log C:\tmp\dotnet\dotnet461\log.txt /x86 /x64 /redist
    register: dotnet_install

  - name: Reboot as required by Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 installer
    win_reboot:
```

The arguments in the install command are important otherwise the installer will fail. You might be able to remove "/log C:\tmp\dotnet\dotnet461\log.txt", but I'll leave it to you to test that out :D

Also this is not idempotent. The installer will execute every time. You can get around that by putting these tasks in a separate .yml file and doing a conditional include based on a registry check to see if it is installed.

Like this:

```
  - name: Check for current Microsoft .NET Framework 4 version
    win_reg_stat:
      path: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
      name: Version
    register: dotnet_version

  - name: Install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1
    include: install_dotnet.yml
    when: dotnet_version.value | version_compare('4.6.01', '<', strict=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but hopefully this will help someone: I've been stuck with this issue a while, and wanted to avoid using Chocolatey. I'm provisioning an AWS Windows machine, and turns out I needed to install hot fix KB2919355 (which requires KB2919442).

After installing both hot fixes installation worked, whereas previously the installation of .NET would just hang.

```
- name: Download Hotfixes
  win_get_url:
    url: "{{ item.url }}"
    dest: "C:/{{ item.kb }}.msu"
  with_items:
    - { kb: KB2919442, url: "https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/6/0/D60ED3E0-93A5-4505-8F6A-8D0A5DA16C8A/Windows8.1-KB2919442-x64.msu" }
    - { kb: KB2919355, url: "https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/5/6/256CCCFB-5341-4A8D-A277-8A81B21A1E35/Windows8.1-KB2919355-x64.msu" }

- name: Install KB2919442 Hotfix
  win_hotfix:
    hotfix_kb: KB2919442
    source: "C:/KB2919442.msu"
  register: hotfix_KB2919442

- name: Install KB2919355 Hotfix
  win_hotfix:
    hotfix_kb: KB2919355
    source: "C:/KB2919355.msu"
  register: hotfix_KB2919355

- name: Remove Hotfix Downloads
  win_file:
    path: "C:/{{ item }}.msu"
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - KB2919442
    - KB2912355

- win_reboot:
  when: hotfix_KB2919442.reboot_required or hotfix_KB2919355.reboot_required

- name: Enable .NET Windows features
  win_feature:
    name: as-net-framework, web-asp-net45
    state: present

- name: Install .NET framework
  win_package:
    path: "https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/1/E4173890-A24A-4936-9FC9-AF930FE3FA40/NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
    product_id: "{BD6F5371-DAC1-30F0-9DDE-CAC6791E28C3}"
    state: present
    arguments: /q /norestart
```

Answer (score 4):

the first way is correct, but you have to determine console keys for silent install

```
- name: Install Microsoft NET Framework
  win_package:
    path: "http://path/to/dotNetFramework4.6.1.exe"
    product_id: '{BD6F5371-DAC1-30F0-9DDE-CAC6791E28C3}'
    register: dotnetfx_exe
    arguments: /q /norestart
```

the other problem, that I can't fix is the win_package doesn't supports automatic product_id and this is breaks idempotency, This step runs every time.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using Chocolatey? It has [`DotNet4.6.1`](https://chocolatey.org/packages/DotNet4.6.1) package, so:

```
- win_chocolatey:
    name: dotnet4.6.1
```

or if you prefer moderator-accepted [version](https://chocolatey.org/packages/DotNet4.6.1/4.6.01055.001), add `version: 4.6.01055.001`.

Comment: But chocolatey uses external links, and I have to use internal links only. Is there a way to tell chocolatey to use a JFrog Artifactory?

Comment: That's what I'm getting when trying to install using chocolatey: 
dotnet4.6.1 not installed. An error occurred during installation:  Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was with WinRM.
There is an [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2842230/-out-of-memory-error-on-a-computer-that-has-a-customized-maxmemorypershellmb-quota-set-and-has-wmf-3.0-installed) that handles it, and after you install the hotfix everything is working fine.